# Makefile : Parameterize so that it compiles the highest numbered file

Tags: c, function, makefile, program-entry-point

Im building a make file, and i want it to be *tolerant of the fact that i have multiple main methods*, and possibly only consider the file with the highest alphabetical value as the entrypoint.

Is there a way to do this or something similar?

Comment: Why do you want multiple main entry points?

Comment: Something like making the target depend on `$(firstword $(sort $(wildcard somepattern)))` *might* be close to what you need, it's hard to say as there isn't much info in your question.

Comment: If you update your question with a more specific example, I could improve my answer to be more specific as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do that, depending on what level you want or need to make that decision. Here are three that I know of:

- Find out what to build before actually building something by calling `$(shell find | grep)` or `$(shell grep -R ...)` to identify the files to be built only (inclusion) or filter-out the files not to be built (exclusion).
- Use `objdump` to analyze the object files and filter-out those which have a `main()` function except the last one. You could use `$(shell sort ...)` as a helper or `$(sort ...)`.
- If you know which objects can contain `make`, and you are using a Compiler / Linker combination which allows *weak* declarations that can be shadowed away, you could use `$(sort)` on the list of objects, `$(lastword)` to get the one with the "highest name", and put that first (or last, depending on how your linker resolves) in the list of linker files.